# How can I hande more than one component from parent

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, validation, react-native

I have a parent component and I have a child component;

Parent name is `<Form>`
Child name is `<FormInput>`
Im calling from `form` as `formInput` , Also I have a button into `Form` component the button has a attribute (`disable`), Also I have a local state into parrent component its name is `isButtonDisable`.
So I want to do this;
I check input from `formInput` is valid or not **if both of them is not valid** I should set local state `isButtonDisable = true` and then I should use from `Form`

So how can i handle both child component

`<FormInput 
onChange(this._onChange.bind(this))
onBlur(this._onBlur.bind(this))
/>`

`<FormInput 
onChange(this._onChange.bind(this))
onBlur(this._onBlur.bind(this))
/>`

Comment: I advice you yoo look ad redux forms is you need a simple approach to form in react

Comment: @AlexanderGorelik I need a solution without redux :(

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple solution, you can change it a little for your needs.
[Solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/qk0zro1qm4)